# Why is everything related to nutrition obfuscated in google fit?

Tags: android, google-play-services, google-fit, google-fit-sdk

I'm using Android Studio and I have Google Play services rev.25 installed. I was playing around with the Fitness API. Documentation claims that there should be [DataType.TYPE_NUTRITION](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/fitness/data/DataType.html#TYPE_NUTRITION) but what I see instead is following

```
    zzYW = new DataType("com.google.nutrition.meal", new Field[]{Field.zzZi, Field.FIELD_CALORIES, Field.zzZj, Field.zzZk, Field.zzZl, Field.zzZm, Field.zzZn, Field.zzZo, Field.zzZp, Field.zzZq, Field.zzZr, Field.zzZs, Field.zzZt, Field.zzZu, Field.zzZv, Field.zzZw, Field.zzZx, Field.zzZy});
```

The nutrition stuff in both DataType and Field seems to be obfuscated for some reason. What puzzles me is that when I use the obfuscated values and deploy app to my phone it works... I assumed there was something wrong with my copy of SDK but the phone seems to have the API obfuscated as well...

Also strange that the type should be `com.google.nutrition` but there is no such thing in my (decompiled) DataType. I'm pretty sure I'm doing something wrong but no clue what that is...

Comment: It would've been a problem if the obfuscated code hadn't worked, the purpose if obfuscation is to just make sources less readable, it shouldn't affect the way the compiled code works.

Comment: well obfuscating API would be very strange :)

Comment: Not really, not all of Google's APIs are open source.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ok.. funny... had to post question here to realize where the problem was... maybe it will help someone...

The problem was that I declared requirement for play services 7.0.0 where the nutrition was not available. Changing the gradle build dependencies to following resolved the "problem"

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.5.0'
```

Comment: Congratulations, you just did a [rubber duck debugging](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging)!